# How to access a calling element's id in a jQuery click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am binding a .click() function to a css class, but I want to be able to access the calling element's id from inside this function when it is called. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull it right out of `this`:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    // Do interesting things.
});
```

The `this` in a jQuery click callback is just a DOM object that exposes its attributes as object properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `this` key word:

```
$(".elementClass").click(function () {
   var currentElement = $(this); // refers to the current element

   var theId = currentElement.attr("id");
});
```

Comment: I had thought this is how you would do this, I was just curious if there was a more direct way then calling the attr() function.

Comment: the is the way to get attributes, because u can't call the `element.id` property on an jquery object.

Comment: But `this` isn't a jQuery object in that context, it is a plain old DOM object.